# Tree View for multiple Fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am looking for an elegant way to show a hierarchy (tree) on fragments.

My idea is to show each level on a distinct fragment. By clicking a leaf I would get to the next level in the hierarchy (would be nice to have a pretty sliding animation here too). Finally I would get come to a point where I have leafs, which should lead to a detail view.

I already know tree-view implementations (like http://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/), but I want to have each level on a distinct fragment. Would also be cool to show several levels next to each other on large screens (tablets) like in the Mac filebrowser.

Main reason is, that I want to load the data for each level from a server on request (the tree is quite large), and secondly I want to have a clear layout. On the other hand I don't want to have every level fragment implemented seperately, as the depth can very from branch to branch.

My data currently is in the form, that every tree node is represented by a TreeElement object with an id, a name, the TreeElementType (node or leaf) and a List of TreeElements as childrens. If this structure would have to be modified, it would be doable.

Can anyone think of a good way to realize this?

Best,
Erik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a working solution:

My TreeElement class looks like this:

```
public class TreeElement
{
private int id;
private TreeElementType type;
private String name;

/**
 * List that holds a set of all the children tree elements.
 */
private List<TreeElement> children = new ArrayList<TreeElement>();

/**
 * List that holds a set of the courses associated to the TreeElement.
 * 
 * @see Course
 */
private List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>();

public TreeElement()
{
    this.type = TreeElementType.NODE;
    this.children = new ArrayList<TreeElement>();
}

public TreeElement(int id)
{
    this();
    this.id = id;
}

public TreeElement(int id, String name)
{
    this( id );
    this.name = name;
}

public TreeElement(int id, TreeElementType type, String name)
{
    this( id, name );
    this.type = type;
}

public int getId()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public TreeElementType getType()
{
    return type;
}

public void setType(TreeElementType type)
{
    this.type = type;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public List<TreeElement> getChildren() {
    return children;
}

public void setChildren(List<TreeElement> children) {
    this.children = children;
}

public void addChild(TreeElement child) {
    this.children.add(child);
}

public void addChildren(List<TreeElement> children) {
    this.children.addAll(children);
}

public List<Course> getCourses() {
    return courses;
}

public void setCourses(List<Course> courses) {
    this.courses = courses;
}

public void addCourse(Course course) {
    this.courses.add(course);
}

public void addCourses(List<Course> courses) {
    this.courses.addAll(courses);
}
}
```

These TreeElements thus generate a hierarchical tree. Each TreeElement can additionally hold some courses I want to show in the tree.

The fragment holding all the pager with the pages is this one:

```
public class BrowserSectionFragment extends Fragment {
private BrowserFragmentPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ViewPager mPager;
private List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();

public BrowserSectionFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_browser, container, false);

    /*
     * Add the root TreeElement-fragment, holding the categories of lowest
     * level.
     */
    fragments.add(new BrowserPageFragment(this,TreeContainer.getTreeElement(TreeContainer.ROOT_ID)));

    mAdapter = new BrowserFragmentPagerAdapter(this.getFragmentManager(), fragments);

    mPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {}

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {}

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            while (arg0 < fragments.size()-1) {
                fragments.remove(fragments.size()-1);
            }

            /*
             * notify the adapter of the changes being made
             * causes the adapter to check all elements, if they are still in the
             * list of fragments
             */
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

/**
 * Adds a new fragment to the fragment manager. The data is taken from
 * the children list of the TreeElement.
 * 
 * @param clickedElement
 */
public void addFragmentFromElement(TreeElement clickedElement) {
    fragments.add(new BrowserPageFragment((this),clickedElement));
    mPager.setCurrentItem(fragments.size()-1, true);
}
}
```

Now I need a PagerAdapter, in this case a FragmentStatePagerAdapter, to organize the Fragments:

```
public class BrowserFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
/**
 * List that holds all the fragments which are currently accessible
 * through the Pager.
 */
private List<Fragment> mFragments;

/**
 * Constructor that initializes the list of fragments.
 * 
 * @param fm FragmentsManager
 * @param fragments
 */
public BrowserFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    mFragments = fragments;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragments.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object item) {
    /*
     * See if fragment is still in the list.
     * If yes, the position in the list is returned, if not, POSITION_NONE, 
     * which causes the Pager to delete the related view.
     */
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) item;
    int position = mFragments.indexOf(fragment);

    if (position >= 0) {
        return position;
    } else {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
}
```

Finally I implemented a PageFragment which is showing a ListView:

```
public class BrowserPageFragment extends ListFragment {
public static final String ARG_ELEMENT_ID = "element_id";
TreeElement element;
BrowserSectionFragment frag;
Context context;

public BrowserPageFragment() {
    super();
}

public BrowserPageFragment( BrowserSectionFragment frag, TreeElement element ) {
    this();
    this.frag = frag;
    this.element = element;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /* Creating an array adapter to store the list of countries **/
    BrowserListAdapter adapter = new BrowserListAdapter(inflater.getContext(),element);
    /* Setting the list adapter for the ListFragment */
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    Object clickedElement = l.getAdapter().getItem(position);

    if (clickedElement instanceof TreeElement) {
        frag.addFragmentFromElement((TreeElement) clickedElement);
    } else if (clickedElement instanceof Course) {
        /*
         * Start a new fragment which shows a detail view of the course.
         */
        Course course = (Course) clickedElement;
        int courseId = course.getId();
        CourseContainer.setCourse(courseId, course);

        Fragment fragment = new DetailsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt( DetailsFragment.ARG_COURSE_NUMBER, courseId);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    }
}
}
```

To make it complete, my custom ListAdapter looks like this:

```
public class BrowserListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
TreeElement element;
List<Object> elements = new ArrayList<Object>();

public BrowserListAdapter(Context context, TreeElement element) {
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.element = element;

    elements.addAll(element.getChildren());
    elements.addAll(element.getCourses());
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return elements.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return elements.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    Object item = elements.get(position);
    if (item instanceof TreeElement) {
        return ((TreeElement) item).getId();
    } else if (item instanceof Course) {
        return ((Course) item).getId();
    }

    return -1;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View itemView = (View) mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
    bindView(itemView, position);
    return itemView;
}

private void bindView(View itemView, int position) {
    Object item = getItem(position);
    String text = null;

    if (item instanceof TreeElement) {
        text = ((TreeElement) item).getName();
    } else if (item instanceof Course) {
        text = ((Course) item).getTitle();
    }

    itemView.setId((int) getItemId(position));
    TextView title = (TextView) itemView;
    title.setText(text);
}
}
```

Maybe this solution helps somebody. The only remaining problems here are:

- The constructor of BrowserPageFragment has a constructor with arguments, which is not nice.
- When changing the orientation the Pager jumps to the first page.
- The back-button does not go to the previous page.